# LWC Lightning Datatable Search

Tags: lightning-web-components, wrapper-class, lightning-datatable

I am trying to build a lighting web component which uses lightning datatable with Server side search capabilities.

here is the code: I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

.HTML

```
    <template>  

    <div class="slds-m-around_medium"> 
        <lightning-input type = "search" value={searchKey} onchange={handleKeywordChange}>
        </lightning-input>
    </div>

    <template if:false={Acc} >
                <lightning-datatable 
                                data={Acc}
                                columns={columns}
                                hide-checkbox-column="true"
                                hide-row-number-column="true"
                                key-field="id" >
                </lightning-datatable>
    </template>
```

.JS

```
import { LightningElement, wire, track, api } from 'lwc';

import Id from '@salesforce/user/Id';
import fetchAccounts from '@salesforce/apex/ManageAccounts.fetchAccounts'

const columns = [
    {
        label: 'Account ID',
        fieldName: 'ID',
        editable: true
    }, {
        label: 'Account Name',
        fieldName: 'Name',
        editable: true

    }, {
        label: 'Account Number',
        fieldName: 'AccountNumber',
        editable: true

    }, {
        label: 'Account Type',
        fieldName: 'Type',
        editable: true
    }
];

export default class ManageAccount extends LightningElement {

userId = Id;
@track searchKey;
@track columns = columns;
@track Acc;
@track error;

    renderedCallback(){
        if(this.isSearchChangeExecuted){
            return;
        }
            fetchAccounts({
                userId: this.userId,
                searchKey: this.searchKey
            })
            .then( response => {
                this.Acc = response;
                this.error = undefined;
            })
            .catch (e => {
                this.error = e;
                this.Acc = undefined;
            })
    }

    handleKeywordChange(event){
        this.isSearchChangeExecuted = false;  
        this.searchKey = event.target.value; 
    }
}
```

.controller

```
public with sharing class ManageAccounts {
    @AuraEnabled (cacheable=true)
    public static List<Account> fetchAccounts( string userId, string searchKey){

        List <Account> acclist = new List<Account>();
        string strgkeyword = '%'+searchKey+'%';
        string query = 'SELECT Id, Name, AccountNumber, Type  FROM Account WHERE OwnerId=: userId' ; 
        if(!String.isEmpty(searchKey)){
            query += ' AND Name LIKE \'%'+searchKey+'%\';
        }
        acclist = Database.query(query);
        return acclist;
    }
}
```

- Updated the dynamic query on the controller file based on input from @sfdcfox which was one of the issue.

Comment: Please [edit] this post to clearly state the problem and ask a question, including only the code that is relevant to the problem you're seeing help with. See [ask].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Onchange might not be fired until the input is blurred (lost focus). This is really browser-dependent behavior. You might want to just use onkeyup with a small delay:

```
<lightning-input ... onkeyup={startSearchTimer} ...
```

---

```
timerId;

startSearchTimer(event) {
  clearTimeout(this.timerId);
  this.timerId = setTimeout(this.doSearch.bind(this),500);
}
doSearch() {
  fetchAccounts({userId:this.userId,searchKey:this.searchKey})
  .then(data => {
    this.Acc = data;
    this.error = null;
  })
  .catch(error => {
    this.Acc = null;
    this.error = error;
  });
}
```

Comment: HI @sfdcfox, I tried with onkeyup, still I don't get the data on the datatable. Maybe there is issue with my SOQL?

Comment: @MubeenQawi Oh, yeah, you're missing quotes.

Comment: thanks @sfdcfox, once i fixed the query, i was able to render the data. But the table load and search experience overall is not ideal (due to the delay). But this has helped me test out and convey a message. I might go for client side search for better UX.